# Multiple signatures on PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, signature

I am setting up a PHP form that will allow the usage of multiple signature pads in a CSS table of 10 Rows x 6 Columns with each row having one signature pad in the 6th column each. When I have tried to make multiple signature pads, in the same screen, the app tends to misbehave.

In the past I have tried to use stick HTML5 to make https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad work and had success in doing so for a single signature.

```
    <html>
    <form action="Run_EMAIL_Protocol.php" method="POST">
    <tr> 
    <th> Section 1 </th>
    <th> Section 2 </th>
    <th> Section 3 </th> 
    <th> Section 4 </th>
    <th> Section 5 </th> 
    <th> Signature </th>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Section_1_A"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Section_2_A"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Section_3_A"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Section_4_A"></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Section_5_A"></td>
    <!-- This is where the signature would come into play but for now I will type in a generic item that will not work because I am seeking a method for fixing errors involving trying to make multiple signatures on a single page -->
    <td> <Insert signature app here> </td>
    </tr>

…
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

What I want to be able to do is run the php form through a engine that will convert the output into a html format that can be then run through PHPMailer for output into a office storage API. For now I am stuck on just getting the signature sections to work in tandum. Even working with 5 Signatures would be a good start.

Comment: FYI: you are missing `<table>`, `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.  The rendering might work, but your HTML is invalid.

Comment: It was an example of part of the code nic3500. The issue getting multi signatures to work.